# Polymorphic relation is being capitalized on ONE and only ONE model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

i have this strange issue where on one of my models the relation name for the polymorphic relation is being capitalized, and it isnt on any other model. The culprit is the Like model.

```
class Like extends Model
{
    public function likeable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

when i log the values of the models, i get capitalized properties for Like and lower case for Comment.

```
[2016-04-12 13:24:22] local.INFO: {"user_id":1,"Likeable_type":"App\\Entities\\Post","Likeable_id":64,"updated_at":"2016-04-12 13:24:22","created_at":"2016-04-12 13:24:22","id":170}  
[2016-04-12 13:24:26] local.INFO: {"user_id":1,"company_id":1,"body":"testing 123","commentable_type":"App\\Entities\\Post","commentable_id":64,"updated_at":"2016-04-12 13:24:26","created_at":"2016-04-12 13:24:26","id":4,"created_at_diff_for_humans":"1 second ago"}
```

Comment: How are the columns named in the database? Perhaps you unintentionally capitalised it in the migration? e.g. `$table->morphs('Likeable')`.

Comment: @Nick i already checked that. all lower case.